# Quicksight cut Timestamp after Date

Tags: date, parsing, payload, amazon-quicksight

I'm currently working in QuickSight and I have a problem that I can't solve. I have a calculated field in which returns a string from a payload in the format of

- yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSSZ

Now I want to cut off everything that comes after the T.

I have already tried some code and the functions that come with QuickSight e.g.

parseDate(replace({payload_enrol_date}, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS', '')) or
split({payload_enrol_date}, 'HH:mm:ss.SSS', 5)

I also tried to use FIND but it's not allowed in a calculated field.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try
substring({ColumnName}, 1, 10)

BTW, feel free to try new Generative BI features that QuickSight announced recently. It can help you write expressions like these. More details at https://community.amazonquicksight.com/t/calculation-question-try-out-our-generative-bi-capability-for-creating-calculations-currently-in-public-preview/18883